# Reading unique data from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Let's say I have a table which can contains data like this:

```
id     name      class
--     ----      ------
 1    Joshua      math
 2     Mary      history
 3     Mary      chemistry
 4     Matt      physics
```

As you can see, for "Mary", we have two classes "history" and "chemistry". How do I (with php or and SQL statement) get the data for "Mary" and return it like this:

```
Mary, history, chemistry
```

In other words, I want to get all the data in the table and return them like this:

```
Josuha, math
Marry, history, chemistry
Matt, physics
```

So whenever a user appears multiple times in the table, I get all his/her data in one line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use MySQL's [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) aggregate function.

Comment: That was too easy. I learn a new mysql function tonight. Thank you ;)